# Is there a way to set the gridOptions attribute after OnInit gets called in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, grid

I am trying to enable/disable rowSelection (ui-grid with gridOption-enableRowselection) based on a flag.

The problem hers is I need to do the enable/disable after Oninit , even after registerGrid. I have two different grids but both uses same service and controller and I want to change only the rowSelection for this. for one grid the rows should be selected for other one it should not come.

I tried this in below refresh which get called each time when click on the icon in the grids but still its not working.  whatever set on Oninit is not getting changed.

```
$scope.refresh = function refresh(checks) {
          $scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection = $scope.isSelection();
          $scope.gridOptions.enableSelectAll = $scope.isSelection();
};

 $scope.isSelection = function() {
     if($scope.flagCheck) //flagCheck will be in the scope it's true/ false based on condition
      {
          return true;
      }else
          return false;
};
```

I tried setting onRegister again in the above refresh function like below but the below function did not get called

```
var gridApi = $scope.gridOptions.gridApi;
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection = $scope.isSelection();
        $scope.gridOptions.enableSelectAll = $scope.isSelection();
 };
```

My Question is , is there anyway we can change the gridOptions after onInit gets called , or can we clear the gridOptions anywhere and call the onInit function again.

Can anyone please guide me on this. Thank You so much in Advance.